# What makes my timers run unaccurate?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, timer

I have a class that creates a new timer, and polls a remote queue (over HTTP) on each tick.

```
public void Start()
{
    _timer = new Timer((x) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:MM:ss.fff") + " " + typeof(T).Name);                

        var message = (Message)null;
        var messageBody = (T)null;

        try
        {
            if (!_queue.TryGet(out message))
                return;

                messageBody = (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.Body, typeof(T));

                _messageDispatcher.Dispatch<T>(messageBody);

                _queue.Delete(message.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _errorHandler.Handle(ex, message);
            }                
        }, null, 0, _queueConsumerConfiguration.PollingInterval);            
    }
}
```

If I create eight new instances of this class, set the polling interval to 250ms, and invoke them, I would assume the timer would tick pretty accurately. What's executed inside the timer callback shouldn't matter. However this is not the case.

```
01:03:23.305 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:23.301 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:23.297 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:23.316 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:24.321 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:24.562 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:24.701 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:24.707 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:24.716 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:25.321 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:25.518 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:25.764 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:25.912 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:25.920 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:25.924 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:26.521 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:26.710 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:26.957 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:27.107 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:27.120 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:27.126 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:27.716 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:27.906 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:28.151 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:28.305 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:28.316 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:28.322 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:28.913 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:29.100 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:29.349 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:29.502 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:29.513 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:29.538 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:30.107 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:30.297 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:30.545 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:30.705 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:30.712 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:30.733 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:31.307 MessageSleepForOneSecond
01:03:31.310 MessageSleepForOneSecond
...
```

What's going on? What causes the inaccuracy? Management of the ThreadPool, Windows,...?

Comment: *"I would assume the timer would tick pretty accurately"* Why? Windows is not a real-time operating system. Your code is sharing processor time with plenty of other code.

Comment: To have better accuracy, have timer running every millisecond and count the elapsed time yourself executing only when reaching the interval.

Comment: @CodyGray Exactly, my assumption is wrong. But what's a good way of explaining it; Windows spends so much time switching contexts that it's impossible to be accurate?

Comment: Why would the 'What's executed inside the timer callback' not matter?  Each class has only one timer.  If the HTTP comms takes longer than the timer interval, the timer cannot fire on time.

Comment: What happens to the times if you comment out the HTTP comms?

Comment: @MartinJames It is my understanding that the timer ticks independent from what goes on inside the callback; a new work item will be started on the ThreadPool. I commented out everything, and now it runs more accurate. However, if I put in a sleep of 10 seconds, the ticks will slow down again, and not to once every 10 seconds, but once every 500ms to 1 second. So what's happening inside the callback definitely impacts the accuracy, but not in a one-to-one fashion.

Comment: In that case, you could well get thread/task runaway as the timer issues tasks at a greater rate than they are completing :(  The pool will create more threads at '500ms to 1 second' to try and handle the extra tasks :(

Comment: @MartinJames When I check the number of available threads on the threadpool, I still have plenty left. I see the number decreasing, but I still have over 900 threads left at the end of my run.

Comment: How about fixing the number of tasks and just Sleep() in a while-loop in each task before looping back to pop more HTTP stuff from the queue?

Comment: ..or, instead of fixed Sleep, in each HTTP-loop task, record the start time, end-time, subtract and, if less than [interval], Sleep() for what's left?

Comment: @MartinJames It doesn't matter that much that it's not accurate. I'd like to know what's good way to explain why it's happening.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed as "not constructive", so I've cast a vote to re-open it. **This is absolutely a question that could be expertly answered with facts and references.** In fact, it's already received a great answer in this vein. I cannot figure out why people think "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". Especially in light of Jef's last comment: "I'd like to know what's good way to explain why it's happening." Perhaps that should be make even more clear in the question itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timers are not infinitely accurate, and thread scheduling is not infinitely accurate. Either of them has an accuracy anywhere from 1ms at best (configurable via `timeBeginPeriod`) and 16.7ms by default on current versions of Windows (around 50ms on 15+ year old Windows).

A timer, not infinitely accurate by itself, generates an event that makes a thread from a thread pool ready, which will be scheduled any time later, not accurately, and without any hard guarantees. If other threads are running, then "any time later" may, depending on processor load and thread priority, literally be *any time* later (or even never).

That alone is already enough reason why generally no interval you choose will be accurate (except by coincidence), but in particular an interval of 250ms will not be (because 249ms is the closest multiple of the scheduler's default granularity, so a new thread can *at best* be scheduled after 265.6ms -- and this assumes that a core is available at that exact time, which is not guaranteed).

Also, processing HTTP requests can take quite non-trivial time, so it is very possible that even in absence of other threads, you create more workers than there are cores. Which necessarily means the OS has to make a decision which one to schedule at a particular time. No matter what the scheduler does, there will always eventually be an "unfair" situation towards one or several of the threads, causing them to be "inaccurate".

Similar is true for writing to the console. Writes to the console are synchronized (i.e. when two of your threads write to the console, individual writes may come out in any order, but they are not garbled). Which necessarily means that there is a lock. Whoever gets the lock first, continues. Whoever tries to get the lock a nanosecond later will be blocked. Some other thread takes over the time slice. Eventually, the blocked thread will be made "ready" again, but there is no strict guarantee that this thread will run immediately.

Being ready to run and running are two very different things.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: FYI in this particular scenario it's the threadpool running out of threads since it takes longer than 250ms to execute the callbacks.

Comment: To be more precise, spinning up _new_ threads to be used by the threadpool takes time.

Comment: @JefClaes: That's true, this is another reason which contributes to the problem, yes. Creating threads is a kind of heavyweight operation which involves among other things calling `DllMain` for every loaded library. Also, this is serialized (i.e. only one thread per process starts up at a time), which may very well cause a thread to miss its "appointment".

Comment: One last thing to consider is that once the threadpool is rather occupied (more threads > processors), it will wait for 500ms before starting a new thread.